# JSON Decoding Not Populating Table View

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to parse data from the website movieDatabase.com However there's some issue decoding the data to json and populating my table view.I am not sure why this is happening. Please I need help spotting out the problem. Here's my code. https://github.com/lexypaul13/Movie-Browser/tree/main/Movie-Browser

```
struct Movies: Codable {
    let overview:String?
    let original_title: String?
    let poster_path:String
}


struct ApiResponse:Codable, Hashable {
    let page:Int
    let shows:[Movies]

    enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey {
        case page = "page"
        case shows = "results"
    }
}



class NetworkManger{

    enum EndPoint{
        case showList
    }

    static let shared = NetworkManger()
    private let baseURL : String
    private var  apiKeyPathCompononent :String

    private init(){
        self.baseURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?"
        self.apiKeyPathCompononent =  "api_key=a07e22bc18f5cb106bfe4cc1f83ad8ed"
    }
    private var jsonDecoder:JSONDecoder = {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        return decoder
    }()



    func get<T:Decodable>(_ endPoints: EndPoint, urlString: String,  completed:@escaping(Result<T?,ErroMessage>)->Void){
        guard let url = urlBuilder(endPoint: endPoints) else {
            completed(.failure(.invalidURL))
            return
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ data, response, error in
            if let _ = error {
                completed(.failure(.unableToComplete))
                return
            }

            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode==200 else {
                print(ErroMessage.invalidResponse.rawValue)
                completed(.failure(.invalidResponse))
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else{
                completed(.failure(.invalidData))
                return
            }
            do{
                let apiResponse = try self.jsonDecoder.decode([T].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed(.success(apiResponse as? T))
                }

            } catch{
                print(ErroMessage.invalidData.rawValue)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    private func urlBuilder(endPoint:EndPoint )->URL?{
        switch endPoint {
        case .showList:
            return URL(string: baseURL + apiKeyPathCompononent )
        }
    }

    func getMovies(){
        NetworkManger.shared.get(.showList, urlString: "") { [weak self] (result: Result<[Movies]?,ErroMessage> ) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result{
            case .success(let movies):
                self.movies = movies ?? []
                DispatchQueue.main.async {self.tableView.reloadData()}

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add the error message

Comment: The data received from the server was invalid. Please try again.

Comment: add the sample response, seems like there was an error while decoding the response, also inside catch add `catch{ print(error.localizedDescription)}` to see actual error

Comment: "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format".

Comment: Actually just `print(error)`

Comment: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "poster_path", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"poster_path\", intValue: nil) (\"poster_path\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Your result should be `Result<[Movies],Error>` - there is no need for the optional. You either have an array (possibly) empty in the success case or an error in the failure case. Also, semantically your struct should be `Movie` since it is a singular instance. The array is what gives you multiple movies.

Comment: The type you are trying to decode doesn't match the json you have received. Convert the received data to a string and print it. I think you probably want to decode a `ApiResponse` not a `[Movies]`

Comment: I'm confused isn't that the purpose of generic to work with any type ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228985/discussion-between-paulw11-and-mayowa-paul).

Answer (score 0):

The root object returned from the api is your `ApiResult` struct. This contains an array of movies (which you have mapped to the `shows` property of the `ApiResult`)

You need to change the `getMovies` function so that the right generic type can be inferred and the json decoder can do the right thing

```
func getMovies(){
        NetworkManger.shared.get(.showList, urlString: "") { [weak self] (result: Result<ApiResult,ErroMessage> ) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result{
            case .success(let apiResult):
                self.movies = apiResult.shows
                DispatchQueue.main.async {self.tableView.reloadData()}

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }
    }
```